# Update a slice in a struct passed to a function

Tags: go

Need help in understanding how to update a slice that is contained in a struct and passed to a function.

Function addBookToShelfInLibrary(l *library, shelfid int, b book) - takes as input a library, tries to add to book to the shelf with the id = shelfid (passed as param). The function appends to the books array and also assigns it to books array. What am I missing?

At the end of code run, I expect the books to contain two books, "harrypotter", "bible" but I see only one, i.e. harrypotter. Also, I am passing a pointer to the library but I don't think that matters in this case.

playground code:- https://play.golang.org/p/JrjtLSj-jHI

```
func main() {
    lib := library{
        shelves: []shelf{
            {
                id: 1,
                books: []book{
                    {name: "harrypotter"},
                },
            },
        },
    }
    addBookToShelfInLibrary(&lib, 1, book{name: "bible"})
    fmt.Printf("%v", lib)

}

type library struct {
    shelves []shelf
}
type shelf struct {
    id    int
    books []book
}

type book struct {
    name string
}

func addBookToShelfInLibrary(l *library, shelfid int, b book) {
    for _, s := range (*l).shelves {
        if s.id == shelfid {
            //found shelf, add book
            s.books = append(s.books, b)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answer / explanation in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why this should be closed or what's the reason for a downvote. Ty.

Comment: In `for _, s := ...` the variable `s` is populated by a copy of each element of `l.shelves`. In other words: your code never even tries to modify a shelve in the library, only a copy is ever modified. This is unrelated to slices and append. Start by iterating like `for i := ...` and modifiy the actual sheve like `l.shelves[i]`.

Comment: ah ok, thanks for explaining. Didn't realize this is unrelated to slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement:

```
s := range (*l).shelves
```

the variable `s` is a copy of the slice element.  The later call to append modifies this copy, the not slice element.  Change the code to modify the slice element:

```
func addBookToShelfInLibrary(l *library, shelfid int, b book) {
    for i := range l.shelves {
        s := &l.shelves[i]
        if s.id == shelfid {
            //found shelf, add book
            s.books = append(s.books, b)
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use a pointer to a shelf:

```
type library struct {
    shelves []*shelf
}

lib := library{
    shelves: []*shelf{
        {
 ...
```

All other code remains the same. [Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TbbA9v6N5n9).